# Hibernate one-to-one XML mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I found the following links:

- [Hibernate one to one mapping problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973509/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-problem)
- [Hibernate one-to-one mapping with a reference column (XML mapping)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682169/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-with-a-reference-column-xml-mapping)
- [hibernate one-to-one (on foreign key) vs one-to-one (on primary key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877338/hibernate-one-to-one-on-foreign-key-vs-one-to-one-on-primary-key)

But nothing seems to work.

I have 2 entities:

```
class User {
    Integer userId;
    Profile userProfile;
}

class Profile {
    Integer profileId;
    User user;
}
```

With XML mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.User" table="User" catalog="Proj1" dynamic-update="true">
        <id name="userId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="userId" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="userProfile" class="model.Profile">
        </one-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jun 12, 2013 7:51:22 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.Profile" table="Profile" catalog="Proj1" dynamic-update="true">
        <id name="profileId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="profileId" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="user" class="model.Users" unique="true">
            <column name="userId" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The thing here is, the `User` must have exactly one `Profile` but the `Profile` doesn't necessarily to have one `User` so a `Profile` may have `null` `User`.

Now the problem is every time I fetch a `User` with its associated `Profile`, the `Profile` retrieved is the `Profile` with the `profileId` the same as `userId`, that is if the `User` has `userId` 4 the `Profile` retrieved is the profile with `profileId` 4 as well even though it is supposed to retrieve `Profile` with `userId` 4 not `profileId` 4.

**Update: add Dao code**

```
public User findById( int id ) {
    log.debug("getting User instance with id: " + id);
    try {
        Criteria userCriteria = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);
        userCriteria.add(Restrictions.idEq(id));

        userCriteria.setFetchMode("userProfile", FetchMode.JOIN);

        userCriteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        Users instance = (Users) userCriteria.uniqueResult();

        if(instance == null)
            log.debug("get successful, no instance found");
        else
            log.debug("get successful, instance found");
        return instance;
    }
    catch(RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("get failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share you DAO code?

Comment: I always tend to map `one-to-one` properties as `many-to-one` with a **unique** constraint in DB foreign key. I don't know if that's supposed to solve your problem, but you could try mapping the `userProfile` in your `User` in a similar way you have `user` in your `Profile` entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Originally I had to set the `userProfile` manually every time I need to fetch the associated `userProfile` of a `User` just for a temporary workaround. But I just found this link: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-bidirectional-121

So basically I just have to add `unique="true" not-null="false"` to the `many-to-one` of the `user` in `Profile` xml and add `property-ref="user"` to the `one-to-one` `userProfile` in `User`. I think the key here is the `property-ref="user"`